Switching users in an image recipe using AWS CDK
I'm building an AMI using EC2 Image Builder. This AMI will later be used for some data processing. I use AWS CDK to generate the image recipe.
Now, just like when you set up a physical machine, some steps need to be run as root, but for many it is better to run them as the user that will run the actual processes for which this machine is being set up.
In principle, I could run everything as root, but it has some problems:

it's bad practice
files and folders end up having the wrong ownership
some caching mechanisms fail (because different users have separate caching folders)

Therefore, ideally, I would want to choose for each command who should run it.
I've looked everywhere in the docs of AWS CDK, but haven't found anything related to switching users. I know I can do: sudo -u ec2-user do_something, but this is just ugly (and does not always work).
Any thoughts? Has anyone else experienced this problem before?
